# Change basic assumptions of "add trendline" in excel

Tags: excel, regression, trendline

I'm plotting some interaction effects that stem from a regression in stata. I'm  using excel for convenience. The data are curvilinear and I'm adding a polynomial trendline to maximize the fit. 
The problem I have is that the trendline function seems to assume that the x values are 1, 2, 3 and so on. Although in my graph they are actually 0, 0.1, 0.2, and so on. The resulting trendline equation thus does not make much sense.

Example data:
X axis:

```
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1
```

Y axis:

```
0.365794061
0.391834869
0.411805232
0.424622483
0.429572487
0.426375536
0.415212526
0.396708002
0.371872294
0.342010179
0.308607579
```

This gives a trendline (polynomial, 2) of `-0.0036x^2 + 0.367x + 0.3336` which neatly fits the data (R^2 is over 99%). However, this equation does not allow me to calculate the maximum correctly.

The data itself stem from a negative binomial regression where the key explanatory variable x is present as linear and quadratic effect (creating the curvilinear shape) with `b1 = 0.783 and b2 = -0.953`.

So two alternative questions:

> 1) Is there a way to fix, override, or circumvent the assumption in
>   excel upon which the trendlines are based?
>
> 2) Is there a better way of deriving the actual shape of the curve
>   straight from the coefficients of the negative binomial regression?

Thanks,

Simon

Comment: How did you derive that equation.  I get a different one from the graph, using your posted data and adding in an initial x-axis value of zero.  `y = -0.3566x^2 + 0.2952x + 0.3667`

Comment: I also get different values for the equation using 1, 2 , 3 for the x-values compared with the values you posted, so I don't understand why you conclude that Excel uses integers in place of the actual values. Given your data, I calculate a maximum Y of `0.427791256`.  Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks for your comment. Your results do make sense to me, which is why I don;t understand that I get completely different ones. I am doing exactly the same (including the initial x-axis value of zero) and I get the equation I posted as an outcome. All I do is select the y column - insert, line, first type - and then add the x axis via select data. Then I select add trendline, polynomial and I get what I get. the 0.427 is indeed what I expect to see, no idea why my results are so different.

Comment: Try Inserting a Scatter graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help:

If your version of Excel is 2007 or later, you can use the TREND function which I will demonstrate below.

But to do this graphically, first Insert a Scatter Graph using your x-y coordinates; add a polynomial order 2 trendline, and show the formula.  (I also formatted the trendline so it could be visualized, as it is a very close fit:

[image: Scatter Graph with trendline]

Then reformat the label as showing digits with 15 decimal places (Excel's precision limit), and copy/paste those values to worksheet cells.

[image: m and b statistics]

In A20 enter some new_X value to be used in the formula.  Use those statistics in a formula:

[image: Using raw statistics]

Or, merely use the TREND function for a polynomial 2nd order, again referencing A20 for a new_X

```
=TREND(B2:B12,A2:A12^{1,2},A20^{1,2})
```

Finally, to get the max value of Y, use Solver to maximize either the cell in which the TREND formula is located, or the cell in which you SUM the trendline coefficients

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks again. It's indeed the scatter graph that makes the difference. When doing that the figure looks exactly the same but the trendline is what you say. Thanks so much. No idea why the line graph doesn't work but the scatterplot seems to do the trick. Thanks a lot,.

Comment: To calculate the optimal x-value i simply use the derivative equal to zero, --> m1 / -2m2. :) Problem solved, much appreciated!

Comment: @simon_icl With the Line graph, you are only changing the x-axis labels, and not the x-axis values.  It is designed for textual labels on the x-axis. Examine Excel HELP for a complete description

Comment: @simon_icl As another approach, you can use LINEST to obtain the coefficients.  So the optimal x would be `=INDEX(LINEST($B$2:$B$12,$A$2:$A$12^{1,2}),1,2)/(-2*LINEST($B$2:$B$12,$A$2:$A$12^{1,2}))`

Comment: Aha, nice one. That's indeed going to be more convenient than always copy pasting the values from the graph!

Comment: @simon_icl Just take care to ensure that this is always being done on versions of Excel => 2007.  Earlier versions used a less accurate algorithm for LINEST, if I recall correctly.